# Cant find Foundation/NSObject.h in Linux while build Obj-c Program

Tags: objective-c, linux, gnustep

I was just starting to study obj-c on Ubuntu Linux today, the tutorial that I followed is http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html, when I typed in the code that requires for Foundation/NSObject.h, the error appeared:

> Fraction.h:1: fatal error: Foundation/NSObject.h: No such file or directory

and i searched for the solutions, and found a proper one
`gcc -o Fraction -I/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers
-L/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries
Fraction.m
-ldl
-lobjc`

I tried this, but I found that I cannot find Headers under the Library directory. (My folder of GNUstep is /usr/share/GNUstep).

Does anyone know how to achieve the Headers?
I installed all the dev packages related to GNUstep but still no luck.

Hope I state my question clear enough. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Try with gnustep-config

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` \
    `gnustep-config --objc-libs` Fraction.m -o Fraction
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try that when I get home, and return to this post

Answer (score 0):

GNUStep uses a fairly involved set of gmake macros - I wouldn't expect a simple command-line invocation of gcc to work very well, although to be honest I haven't tried that way myself. I found [Nicolo Pera's tutorial](http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/) and the project's own [reference page](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Make/Manual/make_toc.html) to be quite useful when learning how to write make files for use with GNUStep.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I can't even find the Headers in my computer, which means I have no NSObject.h file in my system. any suggestion?

Comment: According to <http://packages.ubuntu.com>, NSObject.h is provided by the libgnustep-base-dev package - the gnustep-devel package includes that and a number of others in its dependencies, so I'd suggest installing that.

Comment: Incidentally, according to the package manifest, NSObject.h and other Foundation headers should be in /usr/include/GNUstep/Foundation/

Comment: I surely installed that package, but still cannot find the headers, I tried find / -name NSObject.h, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed `gnustep-base` to fix this error:

```
yum install gnustep-base
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, compiling SOPE on CentOS 7, installed

```
yum install gnustep-base-devel
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: Do [edit] the post and clarify as to why gnustep-base-devel is needed and not gnustep-base, as the other answer has already pointed out